# Alamofire 5.5 responseDecodable on JSON array

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to decode an api response that just responds with an array. All the examples I see for using responseDecodable are a dictionary with a data key or something. But when I just pass [Movie].self into as the decoder I get:

```
failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: responseDecodable
```

I'm assuming I'm not doing this right, looking for some help

GET `/request`

**Response:**

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "test"}]
```

```
struct Movie: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

```
AF.request("http://localhost/request", parameters: parameters)
    .responseDecodable(of: [Movie].self) { response in
       debugPrint(response)
    }
```

Comment: It should work, but is that really your JSON? Could you do `print("Response String: \(String(data: response.data!, encoding:.utf8)")` and show the output?

Comment: `debugPrint(response)` should including a full output of the JSON received unless it was extremely large.  In the debugger I like to use `po String(decoding: response.data!, as: UTF8.self) as NSString` to print the JSON, as it avoids `String`'s escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first assign a variable to accept the JSON data. From there, you can display the result. To illustrate:

```
       AF.request("http://localhost/request", parameters: parameters)
.responseDecodable(of: [Movie].self) { response in
                
        let myresult = try? JSON(data: response.data!)
```

then print it:

```
        debugPrint(myresult)
```

If your JSON data is sound, then you should have no problem receiving the data. If your JSON is nested, then, you can drill-down into it:

```
           let myresult = try? JSON(data: response.data!)
           let resultArray = myresult!["result"]
```

and so on.

As for the "KeyNotFound" error ... It's because of what you said ... it's looking for a dictionary key/value pair. That should be resolved once you try the above example. Also, it's good practice to place your "method" in your AF request. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, your JSON didn't return a `name` value, so check that's it's actually supposed to be that key, or mark the value as optional if it's not always returned. `let name: String?`